# capture group with optional substring

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with data of the following form (four examples given, each separated by a new line):

```
some publication, issue no. 3
another publication, issue no. 23
yet another publication
here is another publication
```

I need to extract the publication name and - in case it exists - the issue number. This has to be done with a regex.

So given above data, I am looking for finding the following results:

```
some publication            3
another publication         23
yet another publication     <null>
here is another publication <null>
```

The following pattern works only for data that has the `, issue no. xyz` part:

```
    String underTest = "some publication, issue no. 3";

    String pattern = "(.*?), issue no. (\\d+)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(underTest);

    boolean found = matcher.find();
    if (found) {
        log.info("something found");
        String group1 = matcher.group(1);
        log.info("group1: {}", group1);

        String group2 = matcher.group(2);
        log.info("group2: {}", group2);
    }
```

Any ideas for a regex string which will work for both cases (with and without issue number)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an optional non-capturing group around the optional part:

```
(.*?)(?:, issue no\. (\d+))?
     ^^^                  ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/joVIMB/2)

In your code:

```
String pattern = "(.*?)(?:, issue no\\. (\\d+))?";
```

If you want your pattern to match the whole string, use it with `Matcher#matches()` rather than `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: An alternative - if the issue pattern is at the end of the string, try matching it first with `",\\s*issue\\s*no\\.\\s*(\\d+)$"` using `Matcher#find()`, then the publication is all from the start up to the match start, and the issue number will be in Group 1: https://ideone.com/bZlxnW.

Comment: This was helpful! Today I learned that it's possible to have a capturing group in a non-capturing group.